# returning random values in android

Tags: android, random

I have a button that calls for this function to be ran. It should return a random value between 1 and 6 and should assign to that value a picture. I have it written now so that every value returns the same image. I want it to be such that if the value is 1 it will return image A, if the value is 6 it will return image B, and if the value is 2-5 it will return image C. I am unsure how to impliment the multi-values. I thought a case would work but it does not seem to answer my problem. If you could just point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
protected void rollPlanechaseDice() {
    int i = 0;
    switch (this.mRandom.nextInt(6)) {
    default:
        i = R.drawable.planeswalker_dice;
    case 0:
    case 1:
    }
    while (true) {
        ImageView localImageView = new ImageView(this);
        localImageView.setImageResource(i);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(localImageView)
                .setTitle(R.string.planechase_dice)
                .setPositiveButton(getText(17039370),
                        new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(

DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface,
                                    int 
paramAnonymousInt) {

paramAnonymousDialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create().show();

        i = R.drawable.planeswalker_dice_chaos;
        return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random.nextInt(6) will return a random number between 0 and 5 (never 6)

```
int i = 0;
switch (this.mRandom.nextInt(6)) {
case 0:
    i = R.drawable.planeswalker_plate;
    break;
case 5:
    i = R.drawable.planeswalker_spoon;
    break;
default:
    i = R.drawable.planeswalker_dice;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I added that bit of code in but the emulator now just restarts after hanging for a few seconds, though I get no red erros in the logcat

Comment: I added breaks and it seems to be working just fine now, thank you!

Comment: Oh i forgot the breaks . I really hate switch-case, I always use if-else.